# Find, then convert the year and month to decimal

Tags: excel

```
5 months in role
1 year 11 months in role
5 years 1 month in role
2 years 8 months in role
1 year in role
3 years 9 months in role
```

Hello, I am trying to convert the list above to a decimal date. For example. I want **[3 years 9 months in role]** to be shown in another cell as **3.75** but I am really struggling to figure out a formula. So far I have

```
=LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))
```

but this obviously just grabs the first value before the space. This formula needs to take into account the variations above (sometimes it's only month shown, etc). Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(" 0 Year " & A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(" 0 year " & A1,"year","}}}",{1,2})),0))-3,2))+TRIM(MID(" " & A1 & " 0 month",MIN(IFERROR(FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(" " & A1 & " 0 month","month","}}}",{1,2})),999))-3,2))/12
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly it! I've spent a better part of the morning trying to do this. Really appreciate your help! This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Power query solution.  Assumes a single column Table in Excel named ("Table1") with a Column Header of "Text".  In case it helps!

```html
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    Month = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Month", each if Text.Contains([Text], "month") = true then 
        try Text.Middle([Text], Text.PositionOf([Text], "month") -3, 2) otherwise 
            Text.Middle([Text], Text.PositionOf([Text], "month") -2, 2) else 0),

    Year = Table.AddColumn(Month, "Year", each if Text.Contains([Text], "year") = true then 
        try Text.Middle([Text], Text.PositionOf([Text], "year") -3, 2) otherwise 
            Text.Middle([Text], Text.PositionOf([Text], "year") -2, 2) else 0),

    ToNumber = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Year,{{"Month", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}}),

    Calc = Table.AddColumn(ToNumber, "Calc", each [Year]+([Month]/12))

in
    Calc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First convert total years and months together into number of months.

Eg: 4 years 5 months = 53 months.

Then divide the total months by 12 to get the decimal calculation.

Eg: 53 / 12 = 4.41 years.